# WordPress: applying str_replace to WP_Query search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get all the posts that contain current post's title in their content.

And I have almost achieved that, except for the one thing: for posts that contain the apostrophe or the right quotation mark in their title it returns no result. While posts that contain the current search term with the apostrophe or the right quotation marks are definitely exist.

Here is the code:

```
$title = '"'.str_replace(array("'","’","&#39;","&#8217;"),
array("","","",""),
wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title())).'"';
$args = array(
    's'                 => $title,
    'cat'               => 48,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => date,
    'order'             => desc,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
    echo the_time("Y.m.d");
    echo ': ';
    echo the_title();
    echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

So my idea was to get rid of all the apostrophes and all the right quotation marks in both the search term and the WP_Query search results.

As it can be seen I've successfully (at least I think so) applied `str_replace` to the search term and now it returns

> Im a bad coder

instead of

> I'm a bad coder

But I totally can not get how to apply the same `str_replace` to the WP_Query results.

So I need your help.

Comment: What happens when you make `$title` the `$s` term? Do articles with the search term not return?

Comment: @Wold, everything perfectly returns until apostrophe or right quotation mark appears in search term - then returns nothing as WordPress is unable to search for apostrophes if `str_replace` is not applied or if applied there is no any **Im a bad coder** sentence in the hole WP database, just **I'm a bad coder** (it's an example). But as soon as I change all instances of **I'm a bad coder** to **I am a bad coder**, then on the page titled **I am a bad coder** I could see every post that contains **I am a bad coder** sentence within it. So everything seems to works great but apostrophes and RQMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary (but may be the best at the same time) solution I've run the following SQL query

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'\&\#039\;','\'');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'\&\#8217\;','\'');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'\’','\'');
```

to alter my existing posts, and then redundantly changed

```
$title = '"'.str_replace(array("'","’","&#39;","&#8217;"),
array("","","",""),
wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title())).'"';
```

with

```
$title = '"'.str_replace(array("’","&#39;","&#8217;"),
array("'","'","'"),
wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title())).'"';
```

Seems I have achieved the desired result, at least for now.